# C# generic type parameter being a generic type

Tags: c#, generics

What type constraint should be applied, if any, to make this work:

```cs
abstract class BaseClass<T> where T : ...
{
    T<int> A { get; set; }
    T<int?> B { get; set; }
    T<string> C { get; set; }
}
```

Currently it gives "Error CS0307 The type parameter 'T' cannot be used with type arguments".

Comment: Should it not just be `T A { get; set; } T B { get; set; } T C { get; set; }`?

Comment: Since this is obviously not a valid syntax, what are you trying to achieve there? It’s really not clear. To make “it” work, you could just remove those `<>` and just put `T` there but that’s probably not what you want to do. So explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you would like to express as a constraint is "T must be a generic class accepting one type argument", right?

Comment: You mean like `T` could be `List<>` and so `A` would be a `List<int>`? That's not possible. And I can't think of a good use case for that. Sounds like a design flaw (or just an academic question).

Comment: As already stated, this isn't possible. The closest you could get in this example would be to have 3 generic types (e.g. `TA`, `TB` and `TC`). However as Rene states, there's probably a better way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: @RenéVogt the way it's written now, T could be List<int>, but it could also be IEqualityComparer<int> or Func<int>.

Comment: This would be even super difficult to design conceptually. What if you used a type `T` with type constaints that are not satisfied by your `BaseClass<T>` usage? Now you would have a compile-time issues for a generic type constaint violation in *private* code you possibly cannot control and probably cannot even *see* (so you have no idea what the problem is)

Comment: @KeyurPATEL, no, in your code all the properties would be of the same type T, which is not my case.

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).  What **exactly** are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no simple syntax to achieve what you want, same way like we don't have constraints for other than parameterless constructors and value types, there is no constraint specifying T is generic type.

Comment: My idea is to have a behavioral container `T` that would manage class-level validation of the properties, e.g. `class RequiredValuesClass : BaseClass<Required>` and `class OptionalValuesClass : BaseClass<Optional>`.

Comment: You’re probably better off just implementing those two types separately (maybe come up with a non-generic base type to share logic), especially when there aren’t other types `T` that would go there.

Comment: @poke the non-generic base type does not work, as all non-nullable properties in it would get a default value, which would lead to an ambiguity in the `OptionalValuesClass`.

Comment: Well, I didn’t say implement all of it in the non-generic base. Just the common logic. – Unless you go into actual details of what you are trying to do, we cannot give you clearer suggestions though. It’s just that what you are trying to do here is not possible.

Comment: @poke I see what you mean (hopefully), however the common logic is to deal with common entities, i.e. the base properties in my case. I am going to use the T wrapper as a way to protect underlying values, like `Nullable<>` does, and also provide a validation interface for the common logic: `where T : Requirement`, `class Required : Requirement`, `class Optional : Requirement`, `this.A.IsValid`.

Answer (score 0):

There is solution with restriction: all representatives: `Class1<T>`, `Class2<T>`, of `T<>` should be inherited from one class or interface(`IBase<T>`):

```
public interface IBase<T>
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class Class1<T> : IBase<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public void SomeMethod1(T input)
    {
    }
}

public class Class2<T> : IBase<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public void SomeMethod2(T input)
    {
    }
}

public class BaseClass<T1, T2, T3> 
    where T1 : IBase<int> 
    where T2 : IBase<int?> 
    where T3 : IBase<string>
{
    public T1 A { get; set; }
    public T2 B { get; set; }
    public T3 C { get; set; }        

    public void SomeMethod3()
    {
        A.Value = 3;
        B.Value = null;
        C.Value = "string";
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var test1 = new BaseClass<Class1<int>, Class1<int?>, Class1<string>>();
test1.A.Value = 3;
test1.A.SomeMethod1(3);

var test2 = new BaseClass<Class2<int>, Class2<int?>, Class2<string>>();
test2.C.Value = "string";
test2.A.SomeMethod2(3);
```